# Find Percentage Of Total With Filters In Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

The following is easily done in SQL, but i am having a little trouble doing the same thing in tableau just from the raw data.

The raw data is in the following format.

Date | Crimetype | Crimes

2015-06-01 | Violent | 5

2015-06-01 | Violent | 5

2015-06-02 | Misdemeanor | 3

2015-06-03 | Parking Related | 2

What I want to do is get by date, show the number of all crimes and the number of crimes that are 'Violent' or 'Misdemeanor', and then the percentage of crimes that are 'Violent' or 'Misdemeanor.'

This is super easy to do in SQL but I want to be able to do this in tableau from the raw data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is super easy to do in Tableau as well, and in an interactive way.

For the number of crimes, simply drag SUM(Crimes) to the worksheet.

For the percentage that are Violent or Misdemeanor, I can show you 2 approaches (there are many more, depending on what is your aim).

1. Simply create a field:

   ```
   SUM(IF Crimetype = 'Violent' OR Crimetype = 'Misdemeanor'
          THEN Crimes
       END)
   /
   SUM(Crimes)
   ```

This will give you the percentage of crimes that are either Violent or Misdemeanor

2. A more interactive way to do this is to create field to be used as filter:

   ```
   LOOKUP(ATTR(Crimetype),0)
   ```

When you use this as a filter (important, you need to have the crimetype info in the worksheet, and have the table calculation partition on Crimetype), as it is a table calculation, it filters after all other calculations.

Now you can use a simple Percent of Total table calculation on SUM(Crime) to achieve what you need. More over, you can make a quick filter with the Crimetypes you want to see.

Other way to do this is put Crimetype on the screen, then select one (ore more) and choose hide. It won't appear on screen, but it will be considered for calculations (same as the table calculation filter). But this method is not so interactive

Answer (score 0):

Inox is right that there are many ways to solve your problem. Here is one more.

Right click on the Crimetype field in the data pane and create a set called Violent_or_Misdemeanor (check the appropriate boxes in the panel)

If you put the set on the Rows shelf and SUM(Crimes) on the Columns or Label shelf, you'll see the number of crimes that are in your set and the number that aren't.

Then if you prefer percentages, you can right click on SUM(Crimes) and make a Quick Table Calculation for Percent of Total.

You can do pretty much the same thing in this case by creating a group instead of a set. A group has the advantage of being able to divide rows into more than two categories, but a set can be used in more places (say calculated fields or combined to make new sets)

Comment: Thank you.

This is very helpful. I'm still trying to get used to doing things the tableau way.